# How to Resolve Yum Dependencies for Oracle DB Installation

Tags: ubuntu, software-installation, dependencies, oracle-database

I have a Ubuntu 18 VM and am trying to install an Oracle XE 12c database locally. I have downloaded the related .rpm file and try to install it as instructed via:

```
yum -y localinstall oracle-database-se-18c-1.0.1.x86_64
```

However, I'm getting the following dependency error:

```
yum -y localinstall oracle-database-xe-18c-1.0-1.x86_64.rpm 
Setting up Local Package Process
Examining oracle-database-xe-18c-1.0-1.x86_64.rpm: oracle-database-xe-18c-1.0-1.x86_64
Marking oracle-database-xe-18c-1.0-1.x86_64.rpm to be installed
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package oracle-database-xe-18c.x86_64 0:1.0-1 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: file for package: oracle-database-xe-18c-1.0-1.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: net-tools for package: oracle-database-xe-18c-1.0-1.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: oracle-database-preinstall-18c for package: oracle-database-xe-18c-1.0-1.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: /bin/sh for package: oracle-database-xe-18c-1.0-1.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: /bin/sh for package: oracle-database-xe-18c-1.0-1.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: /bin/sh for package: oracle-database-xe-18c-1.0-1.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: /bin/sh for package: oracle-database-xe-18c-1.0-1.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: /bin/sh for package: oracle-database-xe-18c-1.0-1.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: /bin/sh for package: oracle-database-xe-18c-1.0-1.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: /bin/sh for package: oracle-database-xe-18c-1.0-1.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: /bin/sh for package: oracle-database-xe-18c-1.0-1.x86_64
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: oracle-database-xe-18c-1.0-1.x86_64 (/oracle-database-xe-18c-1.0-1.x86_64)
           Requires: file
Error: Package: oracle-database-xe-18c-1.0-1.x86_64 (/oracle-database-xe-18c-1.0-1.x86_64)
           Requires: net-tools
Error: Package: oracle-database-xe-18c-1.0-1.x86_64 (/oracle-database-xe-18c-1.0-1.x86_64)
           Requires: oracle-database-preinstall-18c
Error: Package: oracle-database-xe-18c-1.0-1.x86_64 (/oracle-database-xe-18c-1.0-1.x86_64)
           Requires: /bin/sh
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

I do have `sh` and `file` (apt-get install net-tools).

I got the same exact error in Debian 9 VM. What seems to be the problem.

Comment: Have you try to install it on Ubuntu way? https://askubuntu.com/a/739718/680869

Comment: And there is a Debian tutorial for Oracle XE Databases - https://wiki.debian.org/DataBase/Oracle - You will get nowhere trying to install an RPM package inside Ubuntu or Debian...

Comment: @RomeoNinov Where do I get the actual zip? The Oracle site only provides .rpm. Besides, the instruction is geared toward 11 which is most likely different from 12c.

Comment: @nwildner Where do I get the actual zip? The Oracle site only provides .rpm.

Comment: install Oracle XE.

Comment: @Malvon , thats because Oracle does not support Debian based distributions(almost all their products will require a Red Hat-like distro). And you need to use a Red Hat or Oracle Linux on your production servers if you ever hope to get support from them. Best you can do here is to put a CentOS Linux VM and then install Oracle on it...

Comment: @nwildner I think I'll go ahead and try CentOS see how far I can go with it. Ubuntu and specially Debian have been really frustrating to work with in this regard (first time using both distributions).